# Saving Excel data to Access DataBase

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I'm planning to save a particular cell reference value to and access database table that includes student name, student #, files selected for the macro.
I have extracted the above performa items in various cells of the excel. this must be saved in the access databse table.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your efforts here. What you have tried till to achieve your target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want to do, using ACCDB format.

```
Sub InsertIntoX2()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, row As Long
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
            "Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Test.accdb;"

    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "tblTrx", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    row = 3    ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row))

        With rs
            .AddNew    ' create a new record
            .Fields("ID") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
            .Fields("Product") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value
            .Fields("ProdDate") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value
            .Update
        End With
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Just set a reference, in Excel, to 'Microsoft Active X Data Object 2.8 Library'.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your quick response. I believe Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not supported by 64 bit OS. Is there any other way ??

Comment: Jet isn't supported on 64-bit, and Microsoft has stated very clearly that it never will be.

Comment: LOL, there's always a way!!  I just updated my original post to accommodate your updated request.  please make the answer as helpful, if indeed it does help you.  My solution worked fine for me.  It should work just as well for you.

Comment: I can't thank you enough !!! Can i have a look at the original answer as well. for  Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ??? Will Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 have problems on 32 bit machine ??

Comment: Mark my answer as 'useful' if it helps you.

Comment: Synatx error in FROM Clause  : "rs.Open " report Log", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable". If i  try "adCmdtext" im getting "Invalid SQL Statement, expected DELETE, INSERT. Need help !!